# How do you pass props to a child of a child component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I need to pass an authorization token to Search.js to make a request to sharepoint. This authentication takes place in App.js and the fetch request takes place in Search.js. I know you pass variables via props but I am confused on how to pass this token to a child of a child component with out re-rendering search.js. Please help!

Component Structure

```
App.js
 |_Dropdown.js
     |_Search.js
```

Comment: `re-render's` shouldn't be a problem until unless if you observe notifiable slowness ... coming to passing props, maybe here you could just drill it or use a context

Comment: What's the difference between "passing down variables via props" and "pass a token". Your token is almost certainly also stored in a variable. Anyhow, since this sounds like something that could be used across the app, you could use a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: @Elias Thanks. useContext seems like it will do the trick.